# Is it possible to have two SDP(Single Date Pickers) in the same component using react-dates?

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

I want to use one SDP for the start date and the second for the end date, I'm using the following code.

```
<SingleDatePicker
 date={this.state.date} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null
 onDateChange={date => this.setState({ date })} // 
 PropTypes.func.isRequired
 focused={this.state.focused} // PropTypes.bool
 onFocusChange={({ focused }) => this.setState({ focused })} // 
 PropTypes.func.isRequired
/>
```

Comment: Which library is that?

Comment: This one https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates

Comment: ok. To your question here is my suggestion you can use two SingleDatePicker components and use first one to manage start date and second one to manage end date.  Wrap them inside a div like <div><SingleDatePicker /><SingleDatePicker /> </div> and manage its state individually.